# Easy Windows GUI to edit content of MySQL tables (must be much simpler than Workbench/etc)

Tags: windows, database, gui, mysql

Looking for a recommendation on a MySQL DB manager with easy and slick UI. It needs to be able to handle direct queries, visually edit tables and databases mostly with mouse clicks. Kinda looking for a more intuitive, easy-to-use design that doesn't clutter me with thousands of buttons, toolbars and unnecessary information on my server.

Just want to see my databases, tables and easily edit them like anyone does in an app like Trello, Asana, Apple Notes/Reminders, Discord etc. My OS is Windows at the moment.

Looked at Workbench, way too hard and cluttered. Just making the connection takes hundreds of clicks and different windows.

Looked at phpMyAdmin. Again, way too many clicks for simple edits and way too many menus that I will never ever use in my life :) (Actually, had to use phpMyAdmin a lot due to shared host standards)

Looked at a few others as well like DBVisualizer, DB Studio Pro and etc.

To be honest, I believe all of the above have really bad UI design and look & feel is also terrible for my eyes. I kinda get the feeling that there's no 'new' stuff that take on the design principles of the current era. It felt like visiting a web-page from 2010 when I took a glance at the software I mentioned.

I'm ok with paid solutions as long as it's not way too pricey like something over 50-60 bucks. Also, as a side note, I may change my db structure to something like mongoDB if there are way better editors/managers for the structure I'm going to use.

Comment: Please check [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) - It works in similar fashion to Phpmyadmin - You will need web server (like Apache) and php installed and working. I am using is on the daily basic. It is super fast.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz hey thanks for your suggestion but I think I made it clear that I don't like phpMyAdmin at all :) I've checked Adminer also, again, too much clutter and non-necessary UI elements. I don't feel like it's intuitive and user friendly.

Thanks for answering and I respect your answer but no that's not what I'm looking for unfortunately.

Comment: There's this fancy thing called a command prompt you can use -- Google `cmd.exe`. If you're not happy with that, then feel free to design a UI yourself.

Comment: `handle direct queries, visually edit tables and databases`: What do you mean by "edit databases"? Do you need to perform complex operations? Do you need to create indexes, etc?

Comment: @JL2210 Well thanks for stating the obvious :) That's why I was going for a paid option; instead of spending the time to create the UI myself, I would rather pay a company who already did that and buy me my own time.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Edit databases is correct but I won't be using heavily complex operations. An example would usage be: I click on the database name, I directly see the tables. When I click on the name of a table, I immediately get the table contents like one sees in Excel for example. Clicking on a cell edits it in-place etc... Just an intuitive and user-friendly UI as I said :)

Comment: You will not need to create tables, right?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Let's say yes :) What would you recommend for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a term I wasn't familiar to: CRUD which stands for Create, read, update and delete. Seems like I was looking for a good CRUD panel generator and that was it. I found this in a quick search: http://crud-admin-generator.com

Probably will be enough for my needs but if I find anything better, I will post it here as well for any future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good article on GUI tools for MySQL here:
https://codingsight.com/10-best-mysql-gui-tools/

dbForge Studio, HeidiSQL and Toad Edge are ones I remember trying in the past, but you can decide via the pros and cons mentioned for each one in that article (the screenshots too can give you a hint on which to try first)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the answer. This is kinda very old for me but I've already found my answer. Check out crud-admin-generator.com as I've mentioned in the answer. That was exactly what I was going for. Still using it heavily to date :)